# Bokeh change properties of individual layers in a nested categorical plot

Tags: bokeh

I have a nested categorical plot with vbars. In my plot, the smallest level label overlap one another depending on the data. I would like to turn that level to visible = False to remove the labels in a python callback. Any ideas how to access the p.xrange or p.xaxis objects to accomplish this?

This is a good example of a nested categorical where I would for example want the year to be non-visible.

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html#nested-categories

Comment: I partially solve the situation by setting the alpha value to 0.0 but I would still like more control of the different levels. For example my middle level categorical should be rotated 90 degrees to improve the appearance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to remove labels (except by writing a custom extension ticker) but as of Bokeh `0.12.16`, it is possible to rotate all levels of categorical ticks, e.g.

```
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = "vertical"
p.xaxis.subgroup_label_orientation = "normal"
p.xaxis.group_label_orientation = 0.8
```